# Display JSON data on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

This project is dealing with database of scientific papers and citations. 
I correctly implemented some PHP to use a users input (DOI) and search our database and pass the data to javascript. The javascript gets the data like so:

```
function getMETA() {
    var json = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;                    
}
```

Using an HTML form with an onClick="getMETA()" the variable is correctly filled with the data and here is an example:

```
var json = [{"doi":"10.1103\/PhysRevB.79.054101","pub_date":"2009-02-02","journal":"Phys. Rev. B","title":"Absence of superconductivity in the high-pressure polymorph of MgB_{2}","authors":"Y. Ma, Y. Wang, and A. R. Oganov","metainfo":"79, 054101 (2009)"}];
```

This database query just contains meta data of the paper selected, I want to just display it on the webpage. This is what I tried:

```
Title: <span id="title"></span><br />
Authors: <span id="authors"></span><br />
Publish Date: <span id="pubdate"></span><br />
Journal: <span id="journal"></span><br />
```

Then I used document.getElementById("journal").innerHTML but this is not working at all. I even tried to just set it to a string like so: document.getElementById("journal").innerHTML = "test"; and nothing is displayed on the webpage. I also tried this as a test:

HTML:

```
<span id="title">TEST</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  var val = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML.value
  alert(val);
```

And I get an alert box that says "undefined"

How can I get this document.getElementById to work? Or do you recommend another way to parse and display the json data on the webpage? Maybe in a border-less table format?

Thanks!

Comment: The JSON has nothing to do with that document.getElementById problem. Could you possibly create a fiddle to demonstrate it to us.

Comment: @wumm means http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `.value` is only used for `<input>` elements. `.innerHTML` by itself should contain the text.

Comment: Does `document.getElementById("title")` return `undefined`? If so, you need to wait until the DOM is ready. Run your code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely trying to query `#title` before it's actually available. To ensure a reference to the DOM element you're after gets returned when you ask for it, execute your code inside a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) handler:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'test';
});
```

Comment: This worked for me to be able to write to the HTML page elements that are loaded AFTER the script. Now how can I pass the json variable and parse it to get only the objects I want?

Answer (score 0):

This would be because `document.getElementById("title").innerHTML` is returning a string.
 It does not have a value property.

http://jsfiddle.net/UAQFJ/1/

Comment: Where he says that he's wondering that this returns a empty string? But why isn't `document.getElementById("journal").innerHTML = "test";`
 ?

Comment: I'm talking about the last part of the question, there it says `<span id="title">TEST</span>`. (I know `...innerHTML.value;` is nonesene) And this main question is, so I understood, why isn't `document.getElementById("journal").innerHTML = "test";` working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running your Javascript after the DOM has been loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").text("test");
});
```

Plain JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "test";
};
```

Comment: He's using plain javascript not jquery!

Comment: @wumm its tagged jquery and by the way you are right about the not returning test (i misread the question). sorry!

Comment: I think that's because of this stupid tagging suggestion function.

Comment: @wumm I've added a plain JS solution. I didn't know that SO coerced people into using inappropriate tags.

Comment: I said suggestion function, didn't I? And some users may click this sometimes strange suggestions.

Comment: I don't post many questions, I mostly answer, so I didn't know it offered tag suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(json[0],function(f,v){    
    $("body").append("<div class='row'><span class='field'>"+f+": </span><span class='value'>"+v+"</span></div>");
})
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KkgS7/)

Comment: Again, he isn't using jquery! just plain javascript!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/KkgS7/

The jsfiddle shows what I currently have. Here is the full code in the order on my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMETA() {                
        var json = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(json) {
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "test title";
            document.getElementById("authors").innerHTML = json[0];
            document.getElementById("pubdate").innerHTML = json[0];
            document.getElementById("journal").innerHTML = json[0];
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>PRAEDICIT</h1>
<h2>How successful your paper will be?</h2>

<form name="inputdoi" id="doi_input" action="" method="post">
<input name="doi_input" id="searchfield" placeholder="Search by DOI" /> 
<input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Look Up" onclick="getMETA()" />
</form><br><br>

Title: <span id="title">test title</span><br />
Authors: <span id="authors"></span><br />
Publish Date: <span id="pubdate"></span><br />
Journal: <span id="journal"></span><br />
```

The "test title" correctly writes to the HTML as you can see. I know that json[0] is not the correct way to get the object out of the json data, this is the last step I need that I can't figure out.

Am I able to pass the json variable like that from getMETA to the new function? Assume the json variable looks like the example in the first post:

```
var json = [{"doi":"10.1103\/PhysRevB.79.054101","pub_date":"2009-02-02","journal":"Phys. Rev. B","title":"Absence of superconductivity in the high-pressure polymorph of MgB_{2}","authors":"Y. Ma, Y. Wang, and A. R. Oganov","metainfo":"79, 054101 (2009)"}];
```

The Webpage Shows this after looking up a paper:
Title: test title
Authors: undefined
Publish Date: undefined
Journal: undefined